# Compact spaces and closed maps

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous and $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, prove $f$ is a closed map. 
My attempt: We can consider a subspace $A$ of $X$ and the result is fairly obvious. However do we have worry about the case where $A$ is not a subspace of $X$?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what it is that you’re doing? I find it hard to see how you could ask that question if you were actually trying to prove the right thing.

Comment: No. All you have to do is show that if $A \subseteq X$ is closed, then $f(A) \subseteq Y$ is closed. If we use the subspace topology on $A$, then the inclusion $i: A \to X$ is continuous and so is the composite $f \circ i$. Meanwhile, $A$ is compact under the subspace topology. Etc.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I am trying to prove that $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets in $Y$. There is a theorem in the book that says that a subspace of a compact space is compact. But I am not quite sure what if $A$ is closed but not a subspace of $X$

Comment: Okay; you’re doing the right thing. The confusion is just one that I didn’t expect. **Every** subset of $X$ is a subspace of $X$. Which term you use, *subset* or *subspace*, is largely a matter of taste. You’ve misstated the theorem, however: the theorem is that a **closed** subset (or subspace) of a compact space is compact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you! That clears a lot of things for me.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It may strike you as pedantic, but I would say that $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the discrete topology is (in terms of underlying sets) still a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with its standard topology.

Comment: @user43208: I wouldn’t. I’d call that a false statement, in fact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott And why is that? I said underlying sets, mind you, where we forget the topology.

Comment: @user43208: You can say that the two spaces have the same underlying set, and you can say that the underlying set of one is a subset of the underlying set of the other, but in neither case are you actually talking about the topological spaces that you mentioned. It is false that $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology is a subset of $\Bbb R$ with the Euclidean topology. The qualification *in terms of underlying sets* doesn’t change that; it just makes the statement a bit incoherent. ‘$\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is a subset of $\langle Y,\tau'\rangle$ in terms of underlying sets’ is not the same as ...

Comment: ... ‘$X\subseteq Y$’.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott When we speak of *subsets*, we are speaking of objects *qua* their underlying sets. Or, to put it otherwise: when you say $X$ is a subset of a structure $\langle Y, \tau'\rangle$, that's (*par abus de langage*) saying $X \subseteq Y$, since there is no preassigned structure $\tau$ on a sub*set* $X$. For example, it is perfectly commonplace to refer to a subset of a group $G$ just to mean a subset of the underlying set, without a group structure on $X$ in sight, and not think of this as "incoherent".

Comment: @user43208: I agree. Where we differ is that I don’t agree that your previous statement was an example of this. *Incoherent* is probably too strong, but at best the parenthetical bit is a clumsy attempt to salvage a sentence that got off on the wrong track by making a statement about the spaces, not the underlying sets. I probably wouldn’t have said anything had you said that it might strike me as pedantic: in fact it had the opposite effect, though I knew what you actually meant.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well, perhaps we should agree to disagree in that case, since it's probably unimportant to the OP, and besides that, I can't figure out how to respond to your last comment (except that I disagree with the second sentence). Life's too short? :-) Ah -- and now that you've amended your last comment, I'll do the same and say that my previous comment, with which you agree, clarifies the meaning of the parenthetical (whose meaning I think ought to have been clear from the get-go).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to consider a subspace. Let $A\subset$ be a closed set in $X$. Then $A$ is compact as $X$ is. Thus $f(A)$ is compact in $Y$. As $Y$ is Hausdorff, every compact set is closed. Thus $f(A)$ is closed and $f$ is a closed map.

Comment: Well, when we say $A$ "is compact" as a space in its own right, we are using the subspace topology.